# Query an array builded from many flat files

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash

Edited :
I have 180 flat files with multidimentional array (each file has 300 columns & 300 rows separated by space)

sample file https://filebin.net/ij7jv4stioekkt6y/sample_file.txt
Will be deleted on 05.06.2021

I'm looking for the optimal solution for query like :

show me values from all files in loop where column = 145 and row = 155

I tried put it all into MySQL and make a query but query execution time is quite "expensive"

Looking for some hints and tips.

Regards
Alex

Comment: Reading and understanding your question also seems expensive for us!. Please share the codes that you tried. And You are talking about files ? and 300 columns ? Totally misleading

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Content updated, hope will be better understand it.

Comment: @Shawn : I can be used, make sense , I will try to use it in a loop "for a in $(....

Comment: if you have to perform a **LOT** of these types of lookups, and performance is desirable, I'd probably look at a database solution; your `'MySQL'` solution may be workable but you'd need to provide more details on what you mean by `quite "expensive"` (eg, post your DDL, query and performance metrics under a `mysql` tag); I'm **guessing** your (`MySQL`) performance issue is related to a missing/incorrect index and/or a poorly formed query ... ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> show me values from all files in loop where column = 145 and row = 155

Using GNU `awk`:

```sh
gawk 'FNR == 155 { print $145; nextfile }' *.txt
```

Translated: For each file's 155th line, print the 145th column and skip on to the next file (Avoids reading any more lines in the file for the sake of efficiency). Replace `*.txt` with the appropriate shell wildcard pattern to match all your input files.

As part of a `bash` loop over those values:

```sh
while read -r value; do
    # something
done < <(gawk 'FNR = 155 { print $145; nextfile }' *.txt)
```

To make the row and column based on shell variables (`row` and `col`) instead of hardcoded values:

```sh
gawk 'FNR == row { print $col; nextfile }' "row=$row" "col=$col" *.txt
```